# Special handling of /dev/null in open and write?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, dev-null

according to a hint from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401193/after-segfault-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-pointer-is-still-valid) I want to analyze pointers, if their dereferencing would cause an segmentation faults or not. The idea is to write code like this:

```
bool IsPointerValid( void* pPointer )
{
    // when opening "/tmp/hugo" here, it works fine... but not with /dev/null??
    int iFD = open( "/dev/null", O_WRONLY );
    int iBytesWritten = write( iFD, pPointer, 4 );
    close( iFD );

    return iBytesWritten > 0;
}
```

But whatevery I pass to `IsPointerValid(..)`, it returns always true - because `iBytesWritten` is always `4`. But when opening `"/tmp/testfile"` or a fifo, it works like expected: Passing the NULL pointer to `write(..)`, it returns `-1`.

What is the reason for this special treating of `"/dev/null"`?

Thanks,

Charly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a special file, so it brings its own definition of `read` and `write`. (The linux kernel implements polymorphism using function pointers in the driver layer).  Apparently the version of `write` provided by the `/dev/null` device doesn't use the pointer you pass in.

Comment: Hmmm... but that's bad. How can I workaround this problem, without creating a temporary file?

Comment: Since you want to find out if dereferencing a pointer would cause a segfault, why not just dereference it and handle the segfault if one occurs?  No file is needed for that.

Comment: I prefer, to check the pointers in advance - since it's just straightforward and easy to understand.

Comment: @Charly: How do you think that `write` (to a normal file) returns `EFAULT`?  It traps the segfault.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, I just wrote a demo app, and it was working. I'm not sure if it was `EFAULT` - but the `strerror()` returned some similar text...

Comment: @Charly: It's actually `errno` that would be `EFAULT`, the return value from `write` should be `-1`.  If you really want to use the `write` function rather than `signal` or `sigaction` then you can get a file descriptor from `pipe` or `socketpair`.