# Segmentation fault when allocating second array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I quit. This is the most frustrating thing I've ever had to do. Even a non dynamic int array causes segfault. But if I declare it as a float/char whatever array, it works alright.

---

Update:  If i remove the line `MPI_Scatter(A[0], N, MPI_INT, A_row, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` it works fine. Problem is I need it...

---

I'm working on a program but I have a bizarre problem.

The following code works fine (if we suppose that **N** is a multiple of **p**):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"


void main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
   int my_rank, p, N, **A, *diagonals, *A_row;
   MPI_Status status;

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    if (my_rank == 0)  {

        N = 4;
        int *mem = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
        A = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            A[i] = mem + N*i;    

    }
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    A_row = malloc (N * sizeof(int));

    MPI_Scatter(A[0], N, MPI_INT, A_row, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

However, I need to allocate another array (**diagonals**), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"


void main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
   int my_rank, p, N, **A, *diagonals, *A_row;
   MPI_Status status;

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    if (my_rank == 0)  {

        N = 4;
        int *mem = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
        A = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            A[i] = mem + N*i;

        diagonals = malloc (N * sizeof(int));    
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    A_row = malloc (N * sizeof(int));

    MPI_Scatter(A[0], N, MPI_INT, A_row, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I get this segmentation fault (if it helps at all):

```
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] *** Process received signal ***
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] Failing at address: 0x1
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x113d0)[0x7faecc8d23d0]
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] [ 1] a[0x400c85]
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7faecc511830]
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] [ 3] a[0x4009a9]
[teo-VirtualBox:02582] *** End of error message ***
```

Am I missing something obvious?

By the way, I'm not using free(), or doing anything specific because this is not the complete code. It's just a side file that I created for testing.

Comment: For the future, load the program with GDB, and it will tell you what line seg faulted, and you can test the values of certain variables.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar I'm not familiar with gdb. I tried `mpiexec -np 4 a.out -gdb` but it doesn't make any difference in the error message.

Comment: @TeoAlivanoglou Could you try and whittle your code down to a minimum verifiable example i.e. take out everything (mainly the mpi stuff) that you don't need so that we can try running it ourselves?

Comment: @gowrath just edited it

Comment: you should check what `malloc` returns to make sure it's not returning NULL. That being said you're not asking for a whole lot of memory here, so I wouldn't expect any NULLs returned.

Comment: are you sure `my_rank` always equals 0? If not, `A` never gets `malloc`ed, and the called to `MPI_Scatter` will be broken. Same for `N`. The call to `malloc` `A_row` will be called with junk for `N` unless `my_rank==0` (although I don't know what `MPI_Bcast` does with `N`)

Comment: @yano `MPI_Bcast` broadcasts some value to all processes (in my case, `N`). And `MPI_Scatter` sends stuff from `**A` to the other processes, and saves it in `*A_row`

Comment: If it's broadcasting the value of `N` I find it odd that it wants the address of `N`. But that just re-enforces my thought more. If `MPI_Bcast` isn't setting the value of `N`, then you have undefined behavior starting at `A_row = malloc(..);` if `my_rank != 0`. If `my_rank` always equals 0, then why even check? Otherwise, you should have an `else` condition that handles that, or everything involving `N` and `A` should be moved into the `if (my_rank==0)` block.

Comment: @yano First of all, [MPI_Bcast](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Bcast.html). It seems to me that you don't really understand how MPI works. Everything that is outside of the `my_rank == 0` block gets executed by all process.

Comment: no I don't know a thing about MPI. That's irrelevant for what I've suggested. Unless `my_rank==0`, you're going to use uninitialized memory, which is UB.

Comment: @yano incorrect. only the process with `rank == 0` accesses `**A` and everything else (except for `diagonals`) is initialized in all processes

Comment: You say the *Segmentation fault seems to occur before `malloc()`* but at the same time it works if you remove the `MPI_Scatter`? So did you extend the code to check the return values of all `malloc` calls? In any case, guessing is not productive, please [use a debugger (correctly)](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging).

Comment: fair enough .. I'll yield to MPI mystery black box ... hope you figure it out

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I cannot reproduce:

```
linux21:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop/parallel>mpiexec -np 4 a.out
linux21:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop/parallel>mpicc -Wall -std=c99 main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:15: warning: unused variable ‘status’ [-Wunused-variable]
main.c:8:29: warning: variable ‘diagonals’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
linux21:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop/parallel>mpiexec -np 4 a.out
ALL OK
ALL OK
ALL OK
ALL OK
linux21:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop/parallel>
```

with very similar code to yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
   int my_rank, p, N, **A, *diagonals, *A_row;
   MPI_Status status;

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    if (my_rank == 0)  {

        N = 4;
        int *mem = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
        A = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            A[i] = mem + N*i;

        diagonals = malloc (N * sizeof(int));
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    A_row = malloc (N * sizeof(int));

    MPI_Scatter(A[0], N, MPI_INT, A_row, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("ALL OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As a result, I think that your virtualbox has some memory limitations and your `malloc()` fails, check its return value to make sure it's not `NULL`, like this: [How detect malloc failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325940/how-detect-malloc-failure)

Here is my version:

```
linux21:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop/parallel>mpiexec --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.1.3
    Release Date:                            Wed Oct  8 09:37:19 CDT 2014
    CC:                              gcc    
    CXX:                             g++    
    F77:                             gfortran   
    F90:                             gfortran   
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr/local/mpich3' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'CFLAGS= -O2' 'LDFLAGS= ' 'LIBS=-lpthread ' 'CPPFLAGS= -I/usr/local/USB/mpich-3.1.3/src/mpl/include -I/usr/local/USB/mpich-3.1.3/src/mpl/include -I/usr/local/USB/mpich-3.1.3/src/openpa/src -I/usr/local/USB/mpich-3.1.3/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/USB/mpich-3.1.3/src/mpi/romio/include'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Checkpointing libraries available:       
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

---

Maybe the problem is that you don't `free()` your memory? Did you try that?

In general, when using [mpi](/questions/tagged/mpi), try allocating the 2D dynamic array in contiguous memory cells (so that can MPI can freely use its stride, etc.). In general you can do this with these functions:

```
int** allocate2D(int** A, const int N, const int M) {
    int i;
    int *t0;

    A = malloc(M * sizeof (int*)); /* Allocating pointers */
    t0 = malloc(N * M * sizeof (int)); /* Allocating data */
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        A[i] = t0 + i * (N);

    return A;
}

void free2Darray(int** p, const int N) {
    free(p[0]);
    free(p);
}
```

as I explain in [2D dynamic array in continuous memory locations (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-in-continuous-memory-locations-c/)
.

---

Unrelated to your runtime error: [Why do we need to use `int main` and not `void main` in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449851/why-do-we-need-to-use-int-main-and-not-void-main-in-c)

Comment: Isn't it the same as what I've done? Just `mem` instead of `t0`.
Also, thanks for the int vs void page.

Also, what could I free without messing up my data? This program obviously does more things than that.

Comment: Oops @TeoAlivanoglou you do pretty much the same thing, but with the code lines swapped, sorry. Well, you generally `free()` your memory when you no longer needed it, in other words when you don't care about the data. You could that now to see if the complete minimal example runs. I tried in the machines of my university and it worked fine, even without free'ing the memory!

Comment: Wow. I even copy-pasted your code, just to make sure it's 100% the same. I still get the error. Is there any chance that my mpi or gcc are broken? Or maybe VirtualBox limitations?

Comment: I think VirtualBox limitation @TeoAlivanoglou, see my update.

Comment: I can't check if malloc succeded. Segmentation fault seems to occur before `malloc()` returns.

Comment: @TeoAlivanoglou Do you even have to `malloc`? In the code you've shown, you don't. You know `N`, so you know the size of everything at compile time.

Comment: @yano I normally don't know `N`. It has to be dynamic. But I used `N=4;` just for testing purposes.

Comment: @gsamaras I tried it in a normal linux machine. Still no luck. Any chance you can tell me which implementation of mpi you're using?

Comment: @TeoAlivanoglou I updated my answer, good luck, I will upvote your question so that more people come into play, if you find the answer helpful do the same. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Thank you. I'm installing `mpich` as well. I have a feeling it's all `openmpi`'s fault

Comment: Nope. Same with mpich.