# Test errno for ENOMEM, instead of comparing a series of malloc calls to NULL

Tags: c

Normally, one tests for the result of `malloc` to not be `NULL` to known whether memory allocation succeeded. With a series of `malloc` calls, this becomes a lengthy or tedious set of comparisons.

Instead, could one set `errno = 0` at the top of the series of `malloc` calls, and then test for `errno == ENOMEM` at the end?
This assumes if any allocation fails, the program or function can't proceed and has to return/bail out. It also assumes the `malloc` calls are sequential and continuous, and that, as per the manual, `malloc` can only set `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

An example would be something like the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N (1 << 20)

int main()
{
        double *a = NULL;
        double *b = NULL;
        double *c = NULL;

        errno = 0;
        a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
        b = malloc(N * sizeof *b);
        c = malloc(N * sizeof *c);
        if (errno == ENOMEM) {
                perror(NULL);
                free(a);
                free(b);
                free(c);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        errno = 0;

        /* Do interesting stuff */

        free(a);
        free(b);
        free(c);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(The example uses `main()`, but it could also be another function that simply can't be run, but the program might proceed otherwise, and no actual exit from the program happens, and the `free()` calls are necessary.)

I don't see any reason why this can't be done safely, but it's not an idiom I have come across, hence the question.

Comment: My best guess to an answer is either that this is indeed safe, or that malloc setting errno to ENOMEM is less standard across malloc implementations than malloc returning NULL.

Comment: If malloc for a succeded but failed for b and c, wouldn't free(b) and free(c) give error? I know it does not give error for c++ but I am not sure about C compilers.

Comment: Also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325940/how-detect-malloc-failure

Comment: If your `malloc` implementation sets `errno` upon error (which may not be the case, it's platform dependent), then your code is safe.

Comment: @suvenpandey If `malloc` fails, it will also return `NULL`. Calling `free`with a `NULL` parameter is safe in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Platform dependent, or implementation dependent?

Comment: @9769953 sorry, rather implementation dependent

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks; that reflects my suspicion in my first comment at the top.

Comment: if (for instance) the first call to `malloc()` fails then the following calls are successful, then `errno` will be set to `success`.  In other words, the first failure indication is overlayed by the following calls to c library functions.  (in this case the following calls to `malloc()`.  Remember, there is only one `errno` variable and every C library function updates it.

Comment: regarding: `errno = 0;`  User code 'never' needs to modify the variable `errno`

Comment: @user3629249 The above example is perhaps a bad example for errno, but shouldn't a user, after calling a (library) function and possibly handling its error, set `errno` to `0` again, then calling a next (library) function to test for any errors in there?

Comment: the C library functions do not care about the prior value of `errno`, so there is no need to have the user code modify it

Comment: @user3629249 Good point. But what about two consecutive calls to e.g. `fopen()`? For example, if the program can't find one particular file (`errno` will be set), it will try a backup file, and will need to check if that second `fopen()` doesn't fall. Of course, the file pointer would be `NULL`, but `errno` could have more information why it failed: file not found, no read permission etc.

Comment: @user3629249 I can answer that last question myself, I realise: check for `fp == NULL`, then check the value of `errno` to see what the actual error is.

Comment: rather than checking the value of `errno`, just call `perror( "your error message");`  as that will output to `stderr`, both your error message and text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead, could one set errno = 0 at the top of the series of malloc calls, and then test for errno == ENOMEM at the end?

Yes you could as long as your implementation of `malloc` is documented to set `errno` to `ENOMEM`. The specification in the C11 standard (§ 7.22.3.4) only mentions that the pointer returned will be `NULL`, not that `errno` will be set, so your code is technically not portable.

The default implementation of `malloc` in macOS, Windows and in Linux does set `errno` so that's most of the computers in the World covered. However, if true portability is required, at the end just write

```
if (a == NULL || b == NULL || c == NULL)
{
    // Handle the failure
}
```

Addendum: There's no need to reset `errno` back to zero after the `malloc`s.

Comment: Just for completeness, is there a link to the relevant section in the standard, or is that not possible?

Comment: @9769953 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @9769953 I've added the section number. There's no handy HTML version of the standard available on the Internet without handing over a wodge of cash. I have a PDF of a late draft which I got [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) and is, to all intents and purposes identical.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze and JeremyP: Thanks for the addition/link!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not safely do this in a portable manner.

Per [**7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3) of the C standard:

> The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of errno in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function. **The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function** call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.

Since `malloc()` is not documented to set `errno` by the C standard, it's free to munge `errno` on success.